# Function if don't work properly with calculated cells

Tags: excel

I've a problem with excel, whene i scroll down the function i doesn't work, 
what I want is very simple : 
I have two column "H" and "I" 
whene H>0 write H 
else write "I" 
but when I scroll down the function it put 0 in place of the number that exist in "I" column
I joined an image of my problem,
I use MS office 2019, frensh version
Any solution ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll down the function"? (en anglais scroll = faire défiler)

Comment: If by "scroll down" you mean "drag down," can you verify that the value in `H17` is in fact `0`? Does it have decimal places that are hidden by the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're dealing with *text-that-looks-like-numbers*.

Try `=SI(--H7>0;--H7;-I7)`